# How do I display response data in the front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, http, express

I've made `GET` requests to the github API:

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/roadtocode822')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
```

I get the response data. This function lives in the `app.js` file.

Also lives on the `app.js` file is the following code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    Article.find({}, function(err, articles){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('index', {
               title: "Articles",
               articles: articles
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I'm able to query data from my mongodb database through the Article.js mongoose model and send the data to my `index.pug` file.

I want to be able to take the GITHUB response data and also render it in one of my pug view files. I feel like I'm missing some sort of concept in Javascript that's preventing me from achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to parse the response from github?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Github response as a JSON, just use `JSON.parse()`. You won't be able to use your .pug template on the front end, however. That template is interpreted on the server side and is sent from server to client as plain old HTML. If you're interested in front-end templating, check out something like [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/roadtocode822')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
```

from the code above, `response.data` will be a html content because your server returns `res.render`.

in the front-end, you should use `a tag` and `form post` instead of `ajax call` like this

```
<a href="https://api.github.com/users/roadtocode822">Click</a>
```